# Get hotkey to type a random number as if I typed it on a keyboard on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

In many cases I need to not just generate a list of random integers (which is easy), but to type random integers into various software.

For example, to skip a random number of lines (1 to 100) in Vim, I need to type that number into Vim, then type "j".

Ideally a key combination on the keyboard would do something like that.

- I press it. It types `34`.
- I press it. It types `56`.
- I press it. It types `3`.
- ...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an AutoHotkey script that assigns the key combination WindowsKey+F1 to do what is required:

```
#F1::
Random, rand, 1, 100
Send %rand%
return
```